# inserting temporary std::shared_ptr into std::map, is it bad?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm designing a class for my application that implements a lot of standard shared pointers and usage of standard containers such as *std::map* and *std::vector*

It's very specific question to the problem so I just copied a piece of code
from my header for clarification purposes..
here is a snapshot of that declarations from the header:

```
struct Drag;
std::map<short, std::shared_ptr<Drag>> m_drag;
typedef sigc::signal<void, Drag&> signal_bet;
inline signal_bet signal_right_top();
```

and here is one of the functions that uses the above declarations and a temporary shared_ptr which is intended to be used not only in this function but until some late time. that means after the function returns a shared pointer should be still alive because it will be assigned at some point to another shared_ptr.

```
void Table::Field::on_signal_left_top(Drag& drag)
{
    m_drag.insert(std::make_pair(drag.id, std::make_shared<Drag>(this))); // THIS!
    auto iter = m_drag.find(drag.id);
    *iter->second = drag;
    iter->second->cx = 0 - iter->second->tx;
    iter->second->cy = 0 - iter->second->ty;

    invalidate_window();
}
```

the above function first insert a new shared_ptr and then assigns the values from one object into another,

What I need from your answer is to tell whether is it safe to insert temporary shared_ptr into the map and be sure that it will not be a dangling or what ever bad thing.

According to [*THIS*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices) website the above function is not considered safe because it would much better to write it like so:

```
void Table::Field::on_signal_left_top(Drag& drag)
{
    std::shared_ptr pointer = std::make_shared<Drag>(this);
    m_drag.insert(std::make_pair(drag.id, pointer));
    auto iter = m_drag.find(drag.id);
    *iter->second = drag;
    // etc...
 }
```

well one line more in the function.

is it really required to type it like that and why ?

Comment: You do know that [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) overload you're using is returning a `std::pair` that includes an iterator to the just inserted element? That means you don't need the `find` call. The returned `std::pair` also includes a boolean indicator that tells you if the insertion was okay or not, something you don't check for (what if the `find` call returns `end()`?).

Comment: "According to THIS website..." - which specific statement on that website concerns you (and aren't addressed by "The exception safety problem described above may also be eliminated by using [the] `make_shared`...")?

Comment: insert on a map and all stl containers AFAIK use copy-value semantics so it should be fine

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not able to assign the return values of insert to some variable and use it later as an iterator. how do you do that?

Comment: `auto iter = m_drag.insert(std::make_pair(drag.id, pointer)).first;`  But you'll probably also want to test the `second` (and oh, what bad names for the two) to see if you actually inserted something or not.

Comment: @codekiddy Updated my answer on how to use the returned pair. Also see the reference linked in my comment.

Comment: `std::make_shared<Drag>(this)` => fail. You need [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) to create a shared pointer out of thin air.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no difference between the two functions in regard to the `std::shared_ptr`, because the `std::make_pair` function will create a copy of the temporary object before the temporary object is destructed. That copy will in turn be copied into the `std::map`, and will then itself be destructed, leaving you with a copy-of-a-copy in the map. But because the two other objects have been destructed, the reference count of the object in the map will still be one.

---

As for handling the return value from `insert`, it's very simple:

```
auto result = m_drag.insert(...);
if (!result.second)
{
    std::cerr << "Could not insert value\n";
    return;
}

auto iter = result.first;

...
```

Comment: On the other hand... if the objects are copyiable, why bother with dynamic allocation and `std::make_shared` at all.  (And if the purpose is to support polymorphism, then `std::make_shared`, or even an explicit `new` won't cut it; you need to provide a clone function.)

Comment: @James I made it shared because the object is created inside another function that returns a pointer, so I make it managed to be valid.

Comment: @codekiddy Except that you are copying the object, so there's no point.  (You do need something to manage memory where the other function is called.  Why does the creating function return a pointer, and not an object?  Dynamic allocation just makes the code slower, and increases the chances of an error.)

Answer (score 4):

The code in the example given is different from your example code, because it is using the **new** operator instead of `std::make_shared`. The key part of their advice is here:

> Since function arguments are evaluated in unspecified order, it is possible for `new int(2)` to be evaluated first, `g()` second, and we may never get to the `shared_ptr` constructor if `g` throws an exception.

`std::make_shared` eliminates this problem - any dynamic memory allocated while constructing an object within `std::make_shared` will be de-allocated if anything throws. You won't need to worry about temporary `std::shared_ptr`s in this case.